# Connecting to MySQL using python without installing Mysql

Tags: python, mysql-python, python-db-api

Thanks for reading this.

I am working on a project that involves database sync with python. The remote machine is a linux machine with MySQL. The client does not want me to install anything except python and python libraries required for the project. Is it possible to connect to MySQL without installing MySQL though it is a remote machine.

Or suggest me some workaround. I do not mind keeping the executable but I do not want anything to be installed, some workaround. I would love it if the library works just like MySQLdb does.

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in [PyMySql](http://www.pymysql.org/). I didn't test myself but I read that it doesn't require MySql to be installed on the local machine.

Comment: Indeed, it sens a nice project to check.